# How to extend device memory by using SD card partition?

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

I have smartphone (HTC Explorer, Android 4.1.2) with SD card (16 gb, class 10). Unfortunately it have only 100 mb internal memory. Is there any way to programmatically extend internal memory size by using for example ext2 partition on sd card? I ask about full mounting sd card partition to home folder on my smartphone. (Programs App2Sd or Link2Sd e.g. don't work correctly for me).
Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

It might be dangerous process but if you still want to expand you can try to swap internal and external memories.[This thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2066307) show to how.